# Concat and Read Image byte and String byte

Tags: java, byte

So basically I want to concat the image byte and String byte and able to read the string byte when converted back to String format. And I can't read the String part of the byte.
I already tried it in concatenating string to string and it worked perfectly and I thought it might also work with image and string since it is in byte.

```
   BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("src/Client/sample img.jpg"));
   ImageIO.write(img , "jpg", baos);
   baos.flush();
   String information = "\"Image Information\"";
   byte[] buffer = baos.toByteArray();
   byte[] info = information.getBytes();
   byte[] concat = new byte[buffer.length + info.length];
   System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, concat, 0, buffer.length);
   System.arraycopy(info, 0, concat, buffer.length, info.length);
```

And here is how I read if the byte is a readable string

```
StringBuilder ret = new StringBuilder(); 
int i = 0; 
while (concat[i] != 0) 
{ 
    if((char) concat[i] == '"'){
         ret.append((char) concat[i]);
         i++;
         while ((char) concat[i] != '"') 
         {
             ret.append((char) concat[i]);
             i++;
         }
         break;
    }
    i++; 
}
```

So yeah, it is possible to do it like this? If not is there any way to concat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can add 1 int (4 bytes) to the array begining. This int will store length of image array. You can read first 4 bytes from bytearray, recognize image bytearray size (for example, N), then read N image bytes, then string bytes.

I think result shoul be like that:

```
byte[] buffer = baos.toByteArray();
byte[] info = information.getBytes();
byte[] length = intToBytes(buffer.length);
byte[] concat = new byte[length.length + buffer.length + info.length];
System.arraycopy(length, 0, concat, 0, buffer.length);
System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, concat, length.length, buffer.length);
System.arraycopy(info, 0, concat, buffer.length + length.length, info.length);
```

Comment: That seems a very simple answer I never thought, gotta to try it now, thanks

Comment: Adding the length of the images + the 4 bytes for the `length` value, that provides me how to get the data of the image and string. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is the unpacking that is the problem, as the image bytes do not have size info.
Reading an image might drop the string bytes at the end.

```
Path imgPath = Paths.get("src/Client/sample img.jpg");

byte[] packed(Path imgPath, String information) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    //Path imgPath = Paths.get("src/Client/sample img.jpg");
    byte[] buffer = Files.readAllBytes(path);
    byte[] len = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(buffer.length).array());
    baos.write(len); // Would be nice to be able to find the information string.
    baos.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);

    byte[] info = information.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    baos.writer(buffer, info);

    byte[] concat = baos.toByteArray();
    return concat;
}

String unpackedInformation(byte[] packedBytes) {
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(packedBytes);
    int imgLength = bb.getInt();

    byte[] info = Arrays.copyOfRange(packedBytes, Integer.SIZE + imgLength,
            packedBytes.length);
    return new String(info, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
}
```

Also use getBytes and new String with a charset, otherwise the default is used, which differs from platform to platform.

Comment: Yes I just observed that the String are moved to the end of the byte even if it was copied first. Got to check your answer now, Thanks